# insert register contents on a macro

Tags: command-line, macro, register

How can I include the contents of a register when recording a macro?

If I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> I get a "pointer" to register `x`, i.e., my macro will contain `^Rx` instead of the register contents.

**Motivation:**

Often I need to record a macro which involves a substitution using a complex regex:

1. create the regex with the aid of incremental search (`'incsearch'`), and using highlight search results (`'hlsearch'`) to ensure that I'm matching the correct text
2. create the substitution command with `s/<c-r>//<replacement>`, so I end up with `s/<complete regex>/<replacement>`
3. start recording a macro, do some stuff, repeat the substitution with <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>up</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd> (or <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>or <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>), add the end steps and stop recording the macro.

The problem with this approach is that the macro stops working as soon as I use another ex command.

I could copy the `:` to another register and use it on the macro, but then it is necessary to keep avoiding to overwrite that register.

Currently I'm copying the substitution command on a split window an re-typing it, but certainly there must be a less cumbersome solution.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit: Better answer -**

After you search you can do a `:let @z = @/`. This will copy your complex regex into register `z`. You can now freely use `<C-r>z` in your macro without having to retype the regex into your document.

I also realize that you said you didn't want to have worry about overwriting a register. Fun fact: the registers you use for macros are actually the *same* registers that you can yank to. So you *could*:

- Record your macro, say to register `q`, using `<C-r>/` to input your search pattern
- Do `"qp` to see your macro written out
- Delete the resulting `^R/` and replace it with the actual text from your search pattern. (Again using `<C-r>/` to avoid typing it.)
- Do a `"qdd` to then copy the *new* macro back to register `q`
- Use `@q` as needed

Now at least you're only using one register to store the macro, and you don't have to actually reference any other ones.

## Old answer:

Is there anything wrong with writing out `<complexregex>`, yanking it to a register that you don't use very often (Let's say `z`), and then using `<C-r>z` in your macro?

Workflow:

- Type out regex
- Visually select
- Delete to register z: `"zd`
- Record macro, something like: `qq:s/<C-r>z/foo/^Mq`
- Use macro as needed: `@q`

Comment: The problem with copying the substitute command or the regex on another register is (as noted on the question) the need to avoid using that register again. If I record a macro and use the `z` register as auxiliary, and them start recording another macro, I have to remember to check if the previously recorded macro used some auxiliary register. This get out of hand if you need to record a third or fourth macro, thus it is  still better to retype the command.

Comment: @mMontu Yes, I saw that after I posted. Sorry I'll try to read more thoroughly in the future. I've updated my answer with a possible workaround.

Comment: You can always store the pattern in a variable, e.g. `:let search=@/`, and insert that into your macro with `^R=search<CR>`.

Comment: @Antony @Tumbler41 Thanks for the ideas! Both are better than retyping. But I still believe there is something more direct (such as improved `^R<register>` which inserts the register contents) or an improved workflow. This task seems to be common enough to have an easier solution.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't class this solution as difficult:  you're just giving the search register an alternative name, and referring to that in the macro. You can create mappings for saving and inserting the search pattern if that helps.